# use OpenOffice correction feature programmatically in PHP

Tags: php, dictionary, sdk, openoffice.org

I would like to use OpenOffice correction feature programmatically in PHP (that is be able to correct a word if misspelled). I found [PUNO](http://puno.sourceforge.net/install.html) which I believe will help me use the OpenOffice API. However from there I have simply no idea where to go. If someone could give me directions that would be great. Using OpenOffice correction feature isn't a requirement at all. If someone knows about a PHP class that can do some spelling check I would also be interested, however I'm guessing that quality wise, it won't get anywhere close to the OpenOffice correction feature hence my initial request.

**updated:** my aim is to perform American to British English translation so the correction feature must be able to work with American and British English dictionaries.

Comment: +1 simply for pointing me to PUNO, which could be incredibly useful

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a PHP Spell Checker : [AJAX Spell Checker](http://www.broken-
notebook.com/spell_checker/documentation.php). It requires [GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net/).

JQuery PHP based [Spell Checker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/wiki/Documentation) would also be very useful. You can use pspell or Aspell or Google spell.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, my aim is to do American to British English translation so these tools won't help.